# PaperJS when adding symbol to layer, children returns undefined

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm adding symbols (some paths) to a layer and when I'm launching onFrame animation layer's children are undefined, why?

I'm trying to add children with `layer.addChild(placedSymbol);`, layer children length returns correctly but if I `console.log` the child in a for loop  returns as `SymbolItem @5`

Here full example code:
https://codepen.io/mrk1977_02/pen/KKPXbQM?editors=0010

```
setUp();
view.onFrame = function(event) {

  frameAnimation(event, pathA.path, layerA);

}
function setUp(){

  //PATH A
  pathA.path = new Path.Circle({
      center: [0, 0],
      radius: radius,
      fillColor: 'black'
  });
  //pathA.path.opacity = 0;

  layerA = new Layer();
  var symbol = new Symbol(pathA.path);
  placeSymbol(symbol, pathA, layerA);


  //IMAGE
  layerImg = new Layer({
      children: [raster]
  });
  addImage(imgPack);


  //PATH B
  pathB.path = pathA.path.clone();
  //pathB.path.opacity = 0;


  layerB = new Layer();
  var symbol2 = new Symbol(pathB.path);
  placeSymbol(symbol2, pathB, layerB);
}

function placeSymbol(symbol, obj, layer){

  //count = layer.children.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      // The center position is a random point in the view:
      var center = Point.random() * view.size;
      var randomX = Math.sin(90*i)+view.size.width/2;
      var randomY = view.size.height/count*i+radius;
      var placedSymbol = symbol.place(new Point(randomX,randomY));
      //placedSymbol.scale(i / count);
      obj.symbolsArray.push(symbol);
      obj.dotsPosXArray.push(randomX);
      layer.addChild(placedSymbol);
    }
}

function frameAnimation(event, path, layer){
   //layer.activate();

   count = layer.children.length;

   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

     var item = layer.children[i];
     console.log('item:'+item);

     if(item.name != 'packaging'){

         var sinus = Math.sin(event.time*Math.PI*.65 + i);
         //var sinus = Math.sin(event.time + curve + i);

         //Position X
         path.dotsPosXArray[i] = item.position.x;
         item.position.x += sinus * 2;

         path.dotsPrevDirectionsArray[i] = path.dotsDirectionsArray[i];

         if(item.position.x < path.dotsPosXArray[i]){

            path.dotsDirectionsArray[i] = 'neg';
            item.opacity = 1;

            if(path.dotsPrevDirectionsArray[i] != path.dotsDirectionsArray[i]){
              //item.bringToFront();
            }

         }else if(item.position.x > path.dotsPosXArray[i]){

            path.dotsDirectionsArray[i] = 'pos';
            item.opacity = 1;

            if(path.dotsPrevDirectionsArray[i] != path.dotsPrevDirectionsArray[i]){
              //item.sendToBack();
            }
         }

          if(i==1){
            //console.log(item.position.x);
          }

         //Position Y
         item.position.y += (item.bounds.height / 15) +.3;

         if (item.bounds.top > view.size.height) {
           item.position.y = -item.bounds.height;
         }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to do. Your code is incomplete and your codepen link is broken. Could you try to reproduce your issue by reducing your code to the essential part that is problematic so we can help you better ?

Comment: path.dotsPosXArray[i] = item.position.x was the problem, path.dotsPosXArray[i] was null